# Create [jupyter-notebook] tag and synonymize [ipython-notebook] to [jupyter-notebook]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

The [ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipython) developers recently renamed part of their project to [jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter) and weakened the dependencies between [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipython), and the now language-agnostic notebook.

Do we want to reflect this in our tag names? I would suggest introducing the new tag [jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook) and make [ipython-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipython-notebook) a synonym.

If you check [jupyters official web page](http://jupyter.org/), you will find that the introduction already uses the new name:

> The Jupyter Notebook is a web application that allows you to create
> and share documents that contain live code, equations, visualizations
> and explanatory text. Uses include: data cleaning and transformation,
> numerical simulation, statistical modeling, machine learning and much
> more.

Answer (score 2):

Yes in general I think this is correct, necessary and overdue:

- For generic (non-language-specific) issues with browser, keyboard shortcuts etc.
- For language-specific issues with [jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook), we
  also need to tag with the specific language: [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) / [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) / [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) / [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) / or any other future language kernels.

Answer (score -3):

**When should I create new tags?**

> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

**How do I create a new tag?**

> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When
>   creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags must be shorter than 25 characters must use the character set {`a-z 0-9 + # - .`}

Since All the requirements are there. I think that adding the tag `jupiter-notebook` will be very useful.

Source: *Help Center > Privileges > [Create Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)*

Comment: Note it's spelled 'jupYter-notebook`